# Why does libxml_use_internal_errors(true) not respect LIBXML_NOWARNING?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am tying to understand how `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` works. It does not seem to respect the `LIBXML_NOWARNING` flag.

Here is an example using PHP 7.2.4.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( false );
new SimpleXMLElement(
  '<DataSet xmlns="iminvalid"></DataSet>', 
  LIBXML_NOWARNING );
var_dump(sizeof(libxml_get_errors()));
// int(0)
```

As expected, there are no warnings spit out by these statements. The namespace warning is hidden because of `LIBXML_NOWARNING`.

However, this:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
new SimpleXMLElement(
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DataSet xmlns="iminvalid"></DataSet>', 
  LIBXML_NOWARNING );
var_dump(sizeof(libxml_get_errors()));

// int(1)
// xmlns: URI iminvalid is not absolute
```

Unexpectedly returns the invalid uri warning. How is it possible to `libxml_use_internal_errors( true )` and hide xml parsing warnings?

Comment: I doubt `libxml_use_internal_errors()` knows anything about the `SimpleXMLElement` class, they each do their own thing, it's a feature not a bug... :-D

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, I thought that `SimpleXMLElement` uses `libxml` under the hood to parse the xml. So, `libxml` may not know about  `SimpleXMLElement`, but the reverse isn't true. It is definitely true that errors spit out by  `SimpleXMLElement` get stored by `libxml`. And when  `libxml_use_internal_errors( false );` then warnings are ignored, but if `libxml_use_internal_errors( true );` warnings are not ignored. It might be a feature, but it is a poorly documented one. :)

Comment: The same flag was ignored by the DomDocument class and was a bug: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=4df993d89da9b78513a75611421e15e100829695
Maybe it is also considered a bug. I know this is old, maybe it's fixed now?

Comment: Interestingly I don't get a warning raised when I run your second example using php 7.3.15, but it does get captured in lib_xml_get_errors().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of php 7.3.15 it seems to work correctly.
Both examples display no warning, but the second example does capture the warning. The flag does not prevent the capture of the warnings via the function, it only suppresses the warnings from being displayed on the console or web browser.

Comment: I have no way of verifying this now that I'm not longer using php. Thanks for your  answer. Hopefully, it can help someone else.